# How to split a DVD into multiple CDs

Tags: windows-7, dvd, compact-disc

I have Windows 7 bootable DVD, My DVD writer is not able to load a DVD, but it can load CDs. Is there any way that I can convert my windows 7 DVD to multiple CDs so that it can be installed from DVDs?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of burning it into multiple CDs, why don't you use bootable USB with Windows 7 installation instead? Save your CDs and your time as well. I have wrote a blog post to make windows 7 installation from USB on my blog. You can read it [here](http://www.ivankristianto.com/os/windows/install-windows-7-from-usb-flashdrive/1529/). Hope that can help you.
Regards. Ivan.

Comment: i have already tried this, but my motherboard doesnt boot USBs.

Answer (score 3):

Then you can't do it because the installer does not allow you to change disks during the install.

Alternatives:

- Buy/borrow a (USB) DVD-ROM
- Use a second computer or a LiveCD, format a partition on your harddisk as NTFS (version 6), set it as primary/active partition and copy the entire contents of the DVD into that partition. This should allow you to install from harddisk.
- If you have a Windows PE LiveCD, you can also start the installer directly from there.
- You can also try restoring the VHD/WIM image directly to disk, but it's actually a bit complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the old computer's have bios's that only read cd's and hard drives. there is no option to boot from anything else..therefor, the only way you are gonna get windows 8 onto an old computer, is if you load it from a newtwork, or burn windows 8 installation on cd's which is gonna take up about 5 probably.